# Is there any connector available to send data from a webservice to spark for analysis?

Tags: web-services, azure, apache-spark, cloud, analytics

I am trying to implement a webservice in Azure which will get the data through an APP via RESTful interface and the same data will be provided to Spark for analysis. Do I have a connector available for this. I do not want to use Kaffka or Cassendra or influxDB or any other extra component.

Comment: please edit youe post and add some examples :)

Comment: What are you trying to solve exactly ! Spark is just a execution Engine , you still need to write the code of what you need to execute !

Comment: Hello Shivansh , thanks. yes I could realize that I had to open a TCP socket for streaming the data onto Spark and storing into DB for further analysis. As being an embedded guy I am new to the field of analytics...please excuse for limited knowledge.